# Смена fragment в CountDownTimer

Tags: java, android

уважаемые программисты и кодеры, возникла следующая проблема, которую я уже безуспешно пытаюсь исправить без малого день.
У меня есть метод Timer(), который при выполнении условия вызывает метод onStop(). Метод onStop() в свою очередь заменяет фрагмент с одно на другой, и вот собственно проблемма:
при смене фрагмента нужный фрагмент загружается не один раз, а множество(около 100) если метод onStop вызывается при нажатии кнопки "назад" на телефоне, то всё работает корректно. Подскажите пожалуйста почему так происходит и что нужно исправить?

Метод loadFragment():

```
public void loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Метод Timer():

```
public void Timer(){
        mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(20000, 100){

            @Override
            public void onTick(long l) {
                if(mImageSwitcher_1.isShown()||mImageSwitcher_2.isShown()||mImageSwitcher_3.isShown()||
                        mImageSwitcher_4.isShown()|| mImageSwitcher_5.isShown()||mImageSwitcher_6.isShown()||
                        mImageSwitcher_7.isShown()|| mImageSwitcher_9.isShown()) {

                    countTimer = (float) (200 - l/100);
                    countTimer = countTimer/10;
                    timerView.setText("" + countTimer);
                } else {
                    mCountDownTimer.cancel();
                    bool = true;
                    onStop();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                countTimer = 99.0f;
                timerView.setText("Время вышло!");
                onStop();
            }
        }.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if(bool) {
            activity.result = countTimer;
            activity.scale = 9;
            activity.selectedFragment = new GameoverFragment();
            activity.loadFragment(activity.selectedFragment);
        } else {
            activity.selectedFragment = new MainFragment();
            activity.loadFragment(activity.selectedFragment);
        }
    }
```

Зараннее спасибо!

Comment: метод onStop() это колбэк системы, сигнал от системы о завершении работы активити - его нельзя вызывать, когда вам вздумается. Все происходит наоборот - система вызывает его, когда активити закрывается, если этот колбэк сработал, значит активити закрылась. Как скажем будильник срабатывает, когда на часах 7 часов, а не вы запускаете будильник, чтобы наступило 7 часов.

Comment: если вы хотите завершить активити, вызывайте для нее метод `finish()`. он в свою очередь корректно вызовет колбэки системы на закрытие активити, в том числе и onStop()

Comment: понял, спасибо, но я хочу закрыть только этот фрагмент а не всю активити

Comment: чтобы закрыть фрагмент нужно вызвать что то вроде этого `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(frag).commit();` где `frag` - фрагмент, который нужно закрыть. при этом так же вызовутся методы завершения жизненного цикла, как `onStop()`. Если планируется возвращаться в этот фрагмент по кнопке "назад", то его так же нужно добавить в backStack